# Using RESTful architecture to access multidimensional data

Tags: rest, opensearch

How should we use REST to access multidimensional data in an efficient way?  The choices seem to be hi-REST, lo-REST, or OpenSearch (which seems like a specialization of lo-REST).

Answer (score 2):

In order for your system to be RESTful, one of the the requirements is that the client doesn't know up front anything about how your URIs are structured.  This means that you can't write code which builds URIs in a particular way like most twitter clients do.  The conventional wisdom is that in order for a resource to be located, you need to discover its URI in a different place.

However, there are times that you're dealing a countless number of resources in the system, and providing links to each one is just plain stupid.  Multidimensional data fits in this category.  In these cases, it's completely valid to provide the client with rules for URI construction, as long as these rules are discovered at run time.

OpenSearch is absolutely a RESTful solution to this problem, and it's programmer friendly at that.  A lot of the use of OpenSearch is limited to plain human readable HTML search results, but in actuality it can be used for purely machine readable (e.g. atom) search results too:

```
<Url type="application/atom+xml"
     template="...search/?q={searchTerms}"/>
```

This template instructs clients that if you'd like an atom representation, you can go here.  But how does this fit multidimensional data?  The extensibility of OpenSearch comes into play here.  The [OpenSearch time extension](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Time/1.0/Draft_1) describes how to instruct clients to construct URLs that represent searches that are constrained to a specific time range (assuming `xmlns:time` is bound correctly:

```
<Url type="application/atom+xml"
     template="...search/?after={time:start}&amp;before={time:end}"/>
```

If a client sees this template, it can see from the template that it only allows a time constraint.  Let's extend it ourselves.

To extend OpenSearch, I have to designate a namespace and some elements in that namespace to mean something specific.  This should be published somewhere so that others can access the documentation and implement their own servers and clients.  Let's say you want to look a customer up by last name; last name is a pretty generic term, but not universal enough that it's been standardized.  Let's say I define a namespace, bind it to the `name` prefix in my OpenSearch description, and expose the following template:

```
<Url type="application/atom+xml"
     template="...search?lastName={name:last}"/>
```

This template instructs any client that understands my `name` namespace that it can do last-name lookups by filling out the template.

This still isn't multidimensional, but let's add another dimension; geography.  Luckily, there's an [OpenSearch draft extension for geography](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Geo/1.0/Draft_1) which allows searching within a bounding box or a circle:

```
<Url type="application/atom+xml"
     template="...search/?latitude={geo:lat?}&amp;
                          longitude={geo:lon?}&amp;
                          metres={geo:radius?}"/>
```

I'm splitting the template to make it readable.

The template still isn't multidimensional, since it only allows searching within one dimension (geospacial).  So how do you do multidimensional searches?  You provide a template which shows how to do multidimensional searches, that make sense to combine:

E.g. here's a template tha allows me to find people with a given last name in a different region (two dimensions):

```
<Url type="application/atom+xml"
     template="combo-find?customerLastName={name:last}&amp;
                          lat={geo:lat?}&amp;
                          lon={geo:lon?}&amp;
                          radius={geo:radius?}"/>
```

Here's a template that allows me to constrain names, and geospatial, along with a time constraint (although the OpenSearch Time extension doesn't say anything about what time you're looking for):

```
<Url type="application/atom+xml"
     template="...search/?lastName={name:last}&amp;
                          lat={geo:lat?}&amp;
                          lon={geo:lon?}&amp;
                          r={geo:radius?}&amp;
                          after={time:start}&amp;
                          before={time:end}"/>
```

In these examples, the client is free to look into the URI template to figure out what URI template parameters are to be filled out.  So the client will know what dimensions each URI template supports, and can figure out which URI fits best at any one time.

The RESTfulness of all of this is because all of the REST constraints are honored; it's stateless, hypermedia is the engine, it's layered, etc.  OpenSearch is just another hypermedia format, a very good one at that!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my Google search of the terms hi-REST and lo_REST, I don't think either choice will have much bearing on efficiency.  Rather, it is more of a question of [how "correct" you want to be.](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=0df3b480-0ea2-4b2e-8414-a0b67309dceb)

Hi-REST is arguably more "correct," but I doubt that the use of Hi-REST will have any significant effect on efficiency.  The data representation you choose to transport the data (i.e. XML, Binary XML, JSON, etc.) will have a far greater effect on data performance.

Comment: I think Dare's "hi-rest/lo-rest" rant is rather dated.  Today, I think it means more along the lines of "do you support the hypermedia constraint or not".  In my view, if you're not honoring the Hypermedia constraint, it's not REST, but it's just RPC implemented over HTTP.  It shares a lot of the benefits from a fully RESTful system, but it misses out on a few of them.